# Drools: collecting results of a query within a rule

Tags: drools

If I have a query (say with `$invar` and `$outvar`), I can easily get the list of `$outvar` in Java. Is there a way of collecting these in a rule though? I can get a result individually through referencing `$outvar` later, but I'd like to use a collect, accumulate or from if possible.

Thanks

(Edit: to expand)

Take a query where $subject is an unbound variable (by convention)

```
query findDatumsParent( Datum $subject, Datum $parent )
    DatumLink( $parent, $subject;  )
    or
    ( and
        DatumLink( $parent, $narrower; )
        ?findDatumsParent( $subject, $narrower; )
    )
end

// and for completeness
declare DatumLink broader: Datum @key narrower: Datum @key end
```

This can be used simply in a rule

```
rule blah
    when
        $item: Datum( "name"; )
        findDatumsParent( $out, $name; )
    then
        System.out.println("found %s", $out);
end
```

but I want something like

```
rule blah
    when
        $item: Datum( "name"; )
        accumulate( findDatumsParent( $out, $name; ); $set: collectSet($out) )
    then
        System.out.println("found %d items", $out.size());
end
```

getQueryResults can let me set a Collection in Java (with a smidge of wrapping), and I can then manipulate elements in the set, and count them.

But is there any way to work with the bindings the query establishes back in Drools?

Comment: This is extremely unclear, especially without the text of the query and a description (in terms of Java) of what you'd like to have how, when and where.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use a backward chaining query in an accumulate, but I may be mistaken, as there isn't a concise definition of the possible interactions.

But, seeing as you don't need the accumulated set of `$out`s, I sugggest to avoid the issue and simply run the query from rule `blah II` and collect the `$out` set in the traditional (Java) way.

```
QueryResults results =
    kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().getQueryResults( "findDatumsParent", "name" );
List datumList = ...;
for ( QueryResultsRow row : results ) {
    Object datumObj = row.get( "$subject" );
    System.out.println( Datum.class.cast( datumObj ) );
    datumList.add( datumObj );
}
```

You may want to pass a bound variable as the argument to getQueryResults, rather than a string literal ("name").

Comment: But not quite what I'm after. I'd like to be able to count the query results in a rule - going to Java feels messy, and spreads code more than I'd like. I don't want to effectively inline the query as I'm duplicating code and asking for problems when I tweak things. Ofc, it may just not be possible (which would be a shame).